# How to subtract multiple rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

| id | Value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 741.4 | 10 October |
| 1 | 752.7 | 9 October |
| 1 | 582.5 | 11 October |
| 2 | 58.58 | 7 November |
| 2 | 390.9 | 5 November |

And so on...

I have to group by id, and also return the difference for each consecutive days (Latter day - Previous day), from the maximum date for an ID, and the date column will show the previous date the subtraction was performed on
like, for this table, the result will show

| id | Value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -158.9 | 10 October |
| 1 | -11.3 | 9 October |
| 2 | -332.3 | 5 November |

There will be multiple ID's and Multiple dates for each ID.

How can be this achieved without using a cursor?

Comment: Can we **safely** assume that you are really storing and actual date (and time) value in the column `date`? `'10 October'` is *not* a date.

Comment: For that you can use window functions perfectly LAG for example

Comment: Yes @Larnu. Its in datetime format

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming* that `date` is a actual date and time value (as a string value in the format `d MMMM` is not a valid date) then you could use `LAG` within a Common Table Expression (CTE), and the filter your data to give the non-`NULL` values:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.id,
           V.Value,
           V.date,
           LAG(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) - Value AS NewValue
    FROM (VALUES(1,741.4,CONVERT(date,'20221010')),
                (1,752.7,CONVERT(date,'20221009')),
                (1,582.5,CONVERT(date,'20221011')),
                (2,58.58,CONVERT(date,'20221107')),
                (2,390.9,CONVERT(date,'20221105')))V(id,Value,date))
SELECT id,
       NewValue AS Value,
       date
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.NewValue IS NOT NULL;
```

If your column `date` *is* actually a string with values in the format `d MMMM` then firstly, the name is a poor choice. A date contains a day, month *and* year, and your value is missing a year; your column `date` is by definition *not* a date. Also string based data types are a very poor choice of a data type for date and time values. For your data, `'5 November'` would be **before** `'9 October'`, because `'5'` has a *lower* value than `'9'`. If you have such bad data, you *need* to fix that and use an actual [date and time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#DateandTimeDataTypes); you have several to choose from.

Comment: No, the date column is actually in datetime format. I just wrote like this so that the question's legibility increases.
Thanks :)

Comment: *" I just wrote like this so that the question's legibility increases."* It does quite the opposite, @DebjitGhosh .

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does my work. Just a quick question. If I want the latter date rather than the previous date, then, what should change?

Comment: So you want 1 row with `NULL` and the other with a value? You'd need to use `ROW_NUMBER` and filter on that instead